# Core Audio sound driver has an error

Tags: drivers, osx-lion, macbook-pro

I have been using Virtual DJ on my machine.  The setup is where I want audio to play over the headphones and use a USB sound card to play audio into my headphones so I can listen to music before I play it for everybody.

[image]

However, the last time I tried, I got an error message saying "Error in the sound driver of Core Audio.  Your sound card is probably not connected, or the settings are incorrect".

[image]

If I use the headphone by themselves, the USB sound card by itself, or my speakers by themselves, they all work individually.

How do I go about figuring out what's wrong here?

Comment: When was the last time that you updated the app or the drivers? Does the app update itself automatically?

Comment: I do not know how to update the driver.  I would appreciate instruction on it, though.  The app is set to NOT update itself automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Mac guy so not sure. Those are just standard questions that you would want to answer for an issue like this regardless of the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went into the MIDI setup and deleted the entry for Virtual DJ - everything worked fine from that point on.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. This happened once I upgraded my OS. I work around it by going into the system preferences - sound - and selecting the USB Audio.  Then, I open Virtual DJ. Click on config - sound setup.  Then select how you want you audio to play.